# How to fix dynamic environment in gitlab?

Tags: bash, yaml

I have built a "deploy review" stage and deploy job in my yaml file with the following code:

```
deploy review:
  stage: deploy review
  only:
    - merge_requests
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME 
    url: https://crazymonk84-$CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG.surge.sh
  script:
    - npm install -g surge
    - surge --project ./public --domain 
      https://crazymonk84-$CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG.surge.sh
```

When I check the pipeline on my gitlab account, I see the commit on my review branch but I do not see "deploy review" job running. I see "test artifact" "test website" jobs running.

The link to the gitlab project is https://gitlab.com/syed.r.abdullah/my-static-website/tree/review

I took the following steps:

1. Added "deploy review" to the yaml file
2. Created a new branch "review" locally
3. Added the change to the yaml file in review branch
4. Committed the change
5. Pushed the change to gitlab using `git push -u origin review`
6. Visited my pipelines and saw review pipeline in failed state
7. Jobs, inside the review pipeline are "test artifact" and "test website", not "deploy review"

```
image: node

variables:
  STAGING_DOMAIN: crazymonk84-staging.surge.sh
  PRODUCTION_DOMAIN: crazymonk84.surge.sh

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy review
  - deploy staging
  - deploy production
  - production tests
  - cache

cache:
  key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
  policy: pull
  paths:
    - node_modules/

update cache:
  stage: cache
  script:
    - npm install
  only:
    - schedules
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
    policy: push
    paths:
      - node_modules/

build website:
  stage: build
  only: 
    - master
    - merge_requests
  except:
    - schedules
  script:
    - echo $CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
    - npm install -g gatsby-cli
    - npm i xstate@4.6.4
    - gatsby build
    - sed -i "s/%%VERSION%%/$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA/" ./public/index.html
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./public

test website:
  stage: test
  except:
    - schedules
  script:
    - npm install -g gatsby-cli
    - npm i xstate@4.6.4
    - gatsby serve &
    - sleep 3
    - curl "http://localhost:9000" | tac | tac | grep -q "Gatsby"  

test artifact:
  image: alpine
  stage: test
  except:
    - schedules
  script:
    - grep -q "Gatsby" ./public/index.html
  cache: {}

deploy review:
  stage: deploy review
  only:
    - merge_requests
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME 
    url: https://crazymonk84-$CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG.surge.sh
  script:
    - npm install -g surge
    - surge --project ./public --domain https://crazymonk84-$CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG.surge.sh      

deploy staging: 
  stage: deploy staging
  environment: 
    name: staging
    url: http://$STAGING_DOMAIN
  only: 
    - master 
  except:
    - schedules
  script:
    - npm install --global surge
    - surge --project ./public --domain $STAGING_DOMAIN
  cache: {}

deploy production: 
  stage: deploy production
  environment: 
    name: production
    url: http://$PRODUCTION_DOMAIN
  only:
    - master  
  when: manual
  allow_failure: false
  except:
    - schedules
  script:
    - npm install --global surge
    - surge --project ./public --domain $PRODUCTION_DOMAIN
  cache: {}

production tests:
  image: alpine
  stage: production tests
  only: 
    - master
  except:
    - schedules
  script:
    - apk add --no-cache curl
    - curl -s "https://$PRODUCTION_DOMAIN" | grep -q "Hi people"
    - curl -s "https://$PRODUCTION_DOMAIN" | grep -q "$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA"
  cache: {}
```

I am expecting to see "deploy review" as the only job in the pipeline. However, I see "test artifact" and "test website." What can I do to fix the issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution:

Add the following to the **build website** and **deploy review** stages:

```
only:
    - master
    - merge_requests
```

Answer (score 0):

I expect you watched a course by Valentin Despa. I've just come across the same problem. I wonder if he published any solution to the issue.

Basically I'm not positive if I'm correct, but...

if we open the link, there might be found an explanation:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_request_pipelines.html

```
only:
  - merge_requests
```

runs the deploy review stage in a detached mode. We don't have an access to our environment variables since they are protected. What I did was I went to Settings -> CI/CD -> Variables -> got rid of a tick in a protected variable option for both variables.

Then, if you run the pipeline again you'll notice it'll throw an error on ./public.

Play his video Dynamic environments and notice at 4:49 (timeline) there are three green pipelines. You have one only (your pipeline is detached)! Meaning build website stage hasn't been run. That's why you'll see the error relating to ./public since your pipeline knows nothing about Gatsby. We need to install Gatsby first and then build it.

```
deploy review:
  stage: deploy review
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    url: https://yourdomain-$CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG.surge.sh
  only:
    - merge_requests
  script:
    - npm install --silent
    - npm install -g gatsby-cli
    - gatsby build
    - npm install --global surge
    - surge --project ./public --domain yourdomain-$CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG.surge.sh
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./public
```